# How to set a node's type on creation?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, jstree

I want to set a node's type on its creation. This is what I'm trying:

```
$("#tree").jstree("create_node", parentId, {text: "mynode", id: "myid", type: "mytype"}, "last");
```

This doesn't set the type. I know `set_type` exists, but I wonder if this is possible on the node's creation.

Comment: I believe in this answer you'll also find your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341279/jstree-not-creating-node-of-an-specific-type

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your tree full config so please check a few things:

1. you should have `types` plugin enabled in tree config as `"plugins": [ "types" ]`
2. you should configure your `types` e.g. like so:

   ```
   "types" : {
       "tree" : {
           "icon" : 'https://www.jstree.com/tree-icon.png'
       },
       "mytype" : {
           "icon" : 'glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'
       }
   }
   ```

See demo [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vg9mspkL/)